# How to launch an EC2 instance from reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

Once I purchased a reserved instance and i launched an instance with the same specification of the reserved instance. But in billing the launched instance is shown as on-demand instance.

May I know the steps to launch an EC2 instance from a reserved instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your specification really mach, the RI should be applied when parameters match

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html

Comment: Thank you. I purchased one reserved instance in London, but my billing shows the EC2 instance as on demand instance.

Comment: Do you have Zone RI or Regional RI? If it's zone RI, please check if the AZ match as well